# Make Lubuntu's login screen solid color

Tags: lubuntu, login-screen, desktop-background, i3-wm

Since i3 appears to inherit the wallpaper from Lubuntu (16.04)'s login screen, I figure I need to change the latter. I followed [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871801), but to no effect. Not only do I not get the blue background by substituting the original line with `bg=#0000FF` (wrong syntax, no doubt) but old background still shows up. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Does http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2311328&p=13429392#post13429392 help?

Comment: @DKBose No, unfortunately.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Unless you really want to change the wallpaper of the login screen, too, it is probably easier to just change *i3's* wallpaper.  For solid color you can just use `xsetroot -solid "#0000FF"` (from package `x11-xserver-utils`). To auto-run it, just add `exec --no-startup-id xsetroot -solid "#0000FF"` to your *i3* configuration.

Comment: @Adaephon That did the trick! Thank you. I read somewhere that i3 just doesn't deal with wallpaper at all, so I thought I had to go the difficult route.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to change my Login Screen by modifying this file: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` , instructions documented in the [LightDM Ubuntu docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Changing_the_Wallpaper)

```
sudo vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf

#/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
[greeter]                                           
#background=                                        
background=/home/mallory/Pictures/wallz/loginwall.png
hide-user-image=true                                
position="30% 50%"
```

It states in the file: *background = Background file to use, either an image path or a color (e.g. #772953)*